# Inject Vue 'moustache' brackets into HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

I'm learning Vue JS and love it so far. I've got one issue I'm finding difficult to get any ideas on. Is it possible to dynamically 'inject' the moustache brackets (can't find the actual name for these i.e. {{ fooBar }}) into a HTML element? Specific example...

```
  <!-- {{ tweet }} TO BE INJECTED BELOW -->
  <textarea cols="60" rows="4"></textarea>
```

I want to inject {{ tweet }} into a textarea element. This is because in my real-world example I can't access and modify the textarea HTML itself. I've tried using jQuery .val() to inject {{ tweet }}, which it does but as plain text. [This CodePen](https://codepen.io/ajm90UK/pen/zdGVpz) will help explain the situation.

If this simply can't be done, are there any alternatives I could look at to dynamically bind the inaccessible textarea?

Comment: When using templating frameworks like Vue.js you should never directly manipulate the DOM

Comment: Sorry, please assume I can't access the textarea html code (and hence would not be able to add v-model)

Comment: textarea always there but I can't access the raw code to add Vue bindings. i can achieve this in 1 line of code with jQuery, but seems Vue can't manipulate DOM - massive shame!

Comment: Of course Vue can manipulate the DOM, that's exactly what it does. But its renderer can't magically act when something external is manipulating the DOM. `{{tweet}}` is a template expression, it wouldn't do anything in the actual DOM. Vue reads the template and builds the DOM. If you really want to inject this into the DOM with jQuery, you'll have to inject the **actual value** but like I said, it's not a good idea to manually manipulate a DOM that's built by a templating framework.

Comment: It's a bit make or break whether we can go forward with Vue if we can't interact with inaccessible HTML elements - unfortunately we have to build functionality on top of existing 3rd party software rather than our own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html):

> Interpolation on textareas ({{text}}) won't work.
> Use v-model instead.

So with jQuery, you could simply try to add a `v-model` attribute to your textarea...

```js
$(function () {
  $('textarea').attr('v-model', 'text');
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      text: 'Lorem ipsum...'
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ text }}</h1>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: This is ideal, not too much jQuery and Vue still doing most the work - thanks!